# Pycharm interpreter error for Flaskr application (official Flask tutorial sample)

Tags: flask, pycharm

**My context**

- I'm educating myself with Python Flask via the [official tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/tutorial/).
- I'm using [Pycharm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux) (community edition) in [Ubuntu Destkop 16](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes?_ga=1.158009914.184996582.1468653544).

**The issue**

- I open the [sample code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/master/examples/flaskr) of this tutorial as a Pycharm project
- Got the `Invalid Python interpreter` error as below snapshot

**My question**

How can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking for a functional Python installation.

If you open the `2` drop-down you've referenced you'll see a selection of Python installations on your machine.

The better option though, is to create a virtualenv for your current project, so click on the cog icon to the right of the `Project Interpreter` drop-down and click `Create VirtualEnv` and follow the prompts.

Once created, it should pick that VirtualEnv as the default Python interpreter for that project and your error will disappear, though remember, because it's a new virtualenv, it won't yet have Flask etc installed on it.  You can install the Flask library by clicking the `+` icon underneath the cog and searching/installing for Flask.

Alternatively, create a `requirements.txt` file on your project root directory, with `Flask` as the contents, and PyCharm will notice that next time you are in a `.py` file and suggest to automatically install Flask.

Comment: Yeah, adding the `virtualenv`, official guided [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html) after my [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/#newwindow=1&q=pycharm%20flaskr%20tutorial%20interpreter%20error%20with%20virtualenv&rct=j), and poinot it to the after-installed `venv` folder fix the error. Thanks you.